# Python: Best 3D format for real-time rendering?

Tags: python, wxpython, 3d

What is the most convenient or common 3D format for Python? In terms of 3D model loader, rendering, animation support ?

Thank you!

Comment: 3d format? As in, file format? Or are you looking for a python based 3d rendering engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [vPython](http://www.vpython.org/) should do your job.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! That's interesting that everyone suggests that.. I'm wondering though (as I asked Robert below) is there any chance it would prove to be a problem when it'd have to work with OpenCV ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found vPython the easiest, however pyopengl is good if you want to get more specific http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks! You'd suggest vPython instead of OpenGL ? OpenCV will be used in the project as well, would vPython work with that toolkit ? Saying this because from what I saw OpenGL is compatible with OpenCV but i'm not an expert in the field.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best approach is with OpenCV as I'm unfamiliar. Usually in computer graphics you have a mvc (search model view controller). This separation means the view purely displays what is in the model (which is controlled by the controller). So It doesn't matter what you use as inputs to the controller or for rendering the view. If you want your model to update in realtime with your camera then you may wanna look carefully at what is used with openCV for rendering. Also I don't suggest vPython over OpenGL, I just think its more basic (but openGL is easy too)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Panda3d](http://www.panda3d.org/) is useful to you.